# Resource to divide time between several tasks, depending of the number of tasks

Tags: ms-project, gantt

I am using MS Project and OmniPlan.

I work alone, and right know in my plan there are several tasks that can be tackled simultaneously (for example, looking in internet for a street local, to investigate about decoration, investigate about electronics, and to go to the town house in order to ask some questions about the street local permissions).

I want the Gantt diagram to assign 8h between the 4 tasks. So I work 2h in each. But also, when one of the tasks finish, to share 8/3=2.6 hours to the 3 tasks.

By following this logic, this way of calculation should take the same amount of time than the standard: "only 1 task at the same time", in order to calculate the project finish date.

I've seen I can adjust a % to a task. But I don't want a fixed %, I want the program to share my available working time. Right now I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for OmniPlan - but Microsoft Project will not automatically assign resources to tasks.  You could set up all four tasks as fixed duration = 1 day, enter in the 2 hours of work and Project will calculate the assignment units.  However, it will not know that you finished one of the tasks without you telling it and it will most certainly not re-adjust the assignment units for the remaining tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Change to the resource usage to see how the work is split between the tasks

For replaning your time you'll need to write a macro that calculates the time saved. Finds the related tasks and splits the extra time between them

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not driving to the town house while running three different queries.

It appears you have four tasks that get you to a milestone.  Planning tools generally sequence them to determine the earliest date for the milestone, or the slack time until the milestone.

Your tasks would chart as follows:

```
- start - looking in internet for a street locale  -  milestone (done)
     \\ - investigate about decoration             -  //
      \ - investigate about electronics            -  /
        - go to townhouse to investigate...        -
```

Given one resource, they should only work on one of these tasks at a time.  The ordering doesn't matter.  A tool that imposes ordering is adding constraints that don't really exist.  Just ignore the ordering and work the tasks in the order that makes more sense.

A better model might be a list of steps to the milestone.  Pick one step to start with, and when you are done or blocked start another step.  Try to minimize the unfinished steps.  Last time I used it Microsoft Project did not support planning this, but can be used to track progress.  I haven't used OmniPlan, but I suspect it works in a similar manner.

```
milestone
- looking in internet for a street locale
- investigate about decoration 
- investigate about electronics
- go to townhouse to investigate.
```